# How to fix "cannot find symbol" error in java

Tags: java, predicate

Not sure why I am getting this error. I have searched through my code and was not able to find anything that would cause this error. I am aware that this error states that I am missing a variable but in this case I am trying to send it into a method.

Full error :

[image: Screen shot of error]

Code:

```
public List<E> get(Predicate<E> pr){
    List<E> ls = new ArrayList<E>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < table.size()){
    Iterator<E> it2 = table.get(i).iterator();
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            if(pr.test(it2.next())){
                ls.add(it2.next());
            }
        }
    }
    return ls;
}
```

Comment: We will need more code to identify the problem; specifically the code around where you call the method.

Comment: I havent called it yet , i was just given the method title and what im meant to have it do so i start from there and test it after

Comment: Where is class Predicate coming from? Did you import it into your program if it is in a different package?

Comment: Looks like you need to import java.util.function.Predicate;

Comment: I am using import java.util.*; Should i use a more specific import statement ?

Comment: For some reason `import java.util.function.*;` doesn't work but  `import java.util.function.Predicate;` works

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to my error thanks to some helpful comments I needed to import the function package :

```
import java.util.function.*;
```